# Copying text from one text box to another using java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, input, text

I am hoping to get this fixed, so I have a textbox that's for initials and I want to copy that to the next 26 initial boxes so it's a bit easier for the user.

I want to do this on the Client-Side so I don't use up the performance on the server-side.

The issue I am having is that whenever I call the function that's supposed to copy the text over, somehow disables the textbox, I am unable to type anything in the textbox. Please see the code below, please let me know where I am going wrong!

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function copyText() {

            var UI = document.getElementById("txtinitialOriginal").value;

            document.getElementById("initial1").innerHTML = UI;
        }
    </script>
<input type="text" onkeypress="copyText(); return false" runat="server" id="txtinitialOriginal" style="font-size:20px"  /> 

 <asp:TextBox ID="initial1"  placeholder="Initial Here" style="float:right" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's because your using `innerHtml` you should be setting the value instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `InnerHtml` will not set the value of a text box. `InnerHTML` replaces the `HTML` inside of the input.

Try setting the textbox with this value

```
document.getElementById("initial1").value = UI;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("<%= initial1.ClientID %>").value = UI;
```

Edit:

Your textbox is disabled because you have

```
onkeypress="copyText(); return false"
```

you need to `return true`

Comment: Hi there, thanks for replying, unfortunately, I did that as well, but the textbox its self becomes disabled, I can't type anything in the textbox where I want to copy the text from.

Comment: Yup that worked, there is still one issue, when I type in something in the text box, the Initial1 textbox only copies over 1st letter, if I type in 3 letters it only copies over 2 letters, why is that?

Comment: Because the value doesn't change until `onkeypress` is finished. Try another event like `onchange` or `onKeyUp`

Comment: Use `onKeyUp` instead of `onKeyPress`


`keypress`
Fires when an actual character is being inserted in, for instance, a text input. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.    
`keyup`
Fires when the user releases a key, after the default action of that key has been performed.